# Как заполинть массив созданым типом данных с++

Tags: c++, ооп

Только начал активно изучать плюсы. Дошел до ООП.
у меня есть структура типа Person, в котрой хранятся id age name. Я создаю массив типа Person. Как мне его заполнить?

```
    struct Person
{
    std::string  id;
    std::string  age;
    std::string name;
    /* data */
};
int main(){
    std::string id;
    std::string age;
    std::string name;
    Person arr[10];

    for(int i =3;i<3;i++){
        std::cout << "ID: ";
        std::cin >> id;
        std::cout << "AGE: ";
        std::cin >> age;
        std::cout << "NAME: ";
        std::cin >> name;

        arr[i] = id + age + name;
    }
    for(int i=3;i<3;i++){
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: `for(int i =3;i<3;i++)` Ничего не смущает?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat то что в массив задал 10 эелементов а заполняю его только на 3)?

Comment: Даже не на три. Посмотрите еще раз. Если не видите, запустите `for(int i =3;i<3;i++) cout << i << '\n';`.

Answer (score 4):

1. У Вас счётчик цикла начинается с `3` и условие в цикле: `i < 3`. Т.е. цикл не выполнится ни разу, ибо условие сразу даст `false`.
2. Чтобы получить доступ к членам структуры нужно использовать операцию членства (`.`).
   Вот как (скорее всего) должен выглядеть Ваш цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    std::cout << "ID: ";
    std::cin >> arr[i].id;
    std::cout << "AGE: ";
    std::cin >> arr[i].age;
    std::cout << "NAME: ";
    std::cin >> arr[i].name;
}
```

Как видите, переменные `id`, `age` и `name` уже не нужны.
Теперь по поводу цикла вывода. `cout` не знает как выводить Ваш тип данных. Поэтому нужно выводить каждый член отдельно:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    std::cout << arr[i].id << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[i].age << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[i].name << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: на счет второго цикла - реально моя ошибка. Напечатал и не заметил

Answer (score 2):

Прочитайте как происходит обращение к членам структур или классов.

Пример ниже привел:

```
struct Person
{
    std::string  id;
    std::string  age;
    std::string name;
    /* data */
};

int main() {
    std::string id;
    std::string age;
    std::string name;
    Person arr[10];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        std::cout << "ID: ";
        std::cin >> id;
        std::cout << "AGE: ";
        std::cin >> age;
        std::cout << "NAME: ";
        std::cin >> name;

        // записываем в объект
        arr[i].id = id;
        arr[i].age = age;
        arr[i].name = name;
    }

    for(int i=3;i<3;i++){
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

В данном примере можно было вообще не объявлять внутри main еще переменные `id`, `age`, `name`. А сразу использовать `arr[i].id`, `arr[i].age`, `arr[i].name`